# Using geometry variable in PostgreSQL/PostGIS statements

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to write an UPSERT statement to insert or update a row in a PostgresSQL database containing a geometry column. My input is a KML fragment and the following statement works for me as long as the KML is valid.

```
UPDATE area SET shape = ST_GeomFromKML('{the KML}') WHERE area_code = '{the area}';
INSERT INTO area(area_code, shape) SELECT '{the area}', ST_GeomFromKML('{the KML}') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM area WHERE area_code = '{0}');
```

In case it's relevant I am calling this from a C# ASP.NET MVC application using a SqlCommand object, but that shouldn't matter as long as the SQL statement is correct.

The changes I want are to use [ST_IsValid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) and [ST_MakeValid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html) to ensure that the column is correct. Unfortunately my recent database experience is mostly SQL Server with a little MySQL and PostgresSQL statements don't appear to handle variables in the same way.

What I would like is for something like:

```
DECLARE @shape geometry;
SELECT @shape = ST_GeomFromKML('{the KML}');
IF NOT (ST_IsValid(@shape)) SELECT @shape = ST_MakeValid(@shape);
UPDATE area SET shape = @shape WHERE area_code = '{the area}';
INSERT INTO area(area_code, shape) SELECT '{the area}', @shape WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM area WHERE area_code = '{0}');
```

so that I am checking validity and correcting it once in the code. However, even after reading the documentation, I don't understand how to use variables to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you need to write a stored procedure in the PL/pgSQL language (assuming that your kml fragment and "the area" are strings):

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunc(kml text, zip text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE shp geometry;
BEGIN
  shp := ST_GeomFromKML(kml);
  IF NOT (ST_IsValid(shp)) THEN
    shp := ST_MakeValid(shp);
  END IF;
  UPDATE area SET shape = shp WHERE area_code = zip;
  INSERT INTO area (area_code, shape)
    SELECT zip, shp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM area WHERE area_code = zip);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Documentation on PL/pgSQL can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html).

Comment: You could also use a DO-statement when you don't need a result

Comment: Worked and I understand what's happening so accepting and upvoting

Comment: Thanks Andy and welcome to the PostgreSQL community. You'll never look back.